# OpenCV doesn't work on Python?

Tags: python

I go here to install OpenCV on my Mac (I am on OS X 10.11 mbut OS X 10.11 is probably the same method...) http://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-on-yosemite-osx-10-10-x/

so i type in my mac terminal

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv
```

then

```
cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py cv.py
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
```

all commands succesful completed

but... I have an error when importing openCV, why ?

```
python
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
>>> import cv3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv3
```

Comment: So what binary does `python` run? What does `which python` output? What does `import sys; print(sys.path)` tell you where it'll look for modules to import?

Comment: Next, I'd be very wary of linking in a `.so` dynamic module compiled for one Python into the `site-packages` for another.

Comment: `which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`. And `sys.path` returns `['', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', .........]`